# Pure Components and Style/Ref Tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say in React I had a component rendered as so:

```
render() {
   return (<AComponent ref={(ref) => { this.ref = ref}} style={{height: 110}} />);
}
```

And I checked the props versus the nextProps,

```
componentWillReceieveProps(nextProps) {
   if (this.props !== nextProps) {
      this.setState({ ..this.getState(nextProps) });
   }
}
```

Would they always not be shallowly equal because the style prop is being given an object literal and the ref an anonymous function? Or does React have something where style and ref tags are not considered for props? If so, is there any other exclusions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ref` and `key` are special and not actually passed as props.

`style` is just a regular prop. `this.props !== nextProps` would always be true; at the very least you need to shallowly compare those, but you're right that with `style={{height: 110}}`, `this.props.style === nextProps.style` would always be false. You can get around that by pulling out the style into an external variable and using that instead of the inline object.